# Adobe Flash Player Problem

Tags: flash, youtube, internet-explorer-9

I have a website and I am having some problems with the Adobe Flash Player. I use a Youtube Video Player, when two of the videos are played in IE9 64-BIT, then it returns "A javascript on this page is causing the script to slow down or something like that". I wanted to know if someone has a solution to this problem.

You can check this yourself if you have IE9 64-BIT @ [Afghanistan](http://afghans.net/)

Comment: Are you using the final version of IE9?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the latest beta of Adobe Flash Player Square which is for x64 systems.
http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html